# How to pass variable value on Page Object Model

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pageobjects, page-factory

I am creating my project with Page Object Model,

To define simple element, it is simplest to define

```
By loginEmailParse = By.id("signIn-email");
```

and to call it : `driver.findElement(loginEmailParse);`

But, when we have condition with variable,

`By.xpath("//input[@id='" + accountID + "']")` AND

```
By.xpath("//input[@id='" + accountID + "']//following::i[@class='far fa-sign-in addPointer']")
```

Here "accountID" is variable,

How we can define it?

Comment: I'm not quite sure , why are You having 2 selector By.xpath() AND By.xpath(),  are those two elements or?

Comment: Its just example

Comment: This sounds like an [X-Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Instead of asking for help with your solution to the problem, edit your question and ask about the actual problem. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can't create a variable. you'll have to pass the xpath inside a method where you are passing the variable as a parameter.

```
public void clickElement(String accountID){
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='" + accountID + "']")).click();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your question and the sampple code provided below, let us assume invoking `click()` on element *elemA* makes another element **clickable** within the [DOM Tree](https://javascript.info/dom-nodes) for which you need to induce [WebDriverWait](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.html) in-conjuction with [ExpectedConditions](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html) as follows:

```
public class LoginPageNew 
{

    WebDriver driver;

    //constructor
    public LoginPageNew(WebDriver loginDriver)
    {
        this.driver=loginDriver;
    }

    @FindBy(id="element1") 
    @CacheLookup
    WebElement elemA;

    public void login_wordpress(String accountID)
    {
        elemA.click();
        new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@id='" + accountID + "']//following::i[@class='far fa-sign-in addPointer']"))).click();
    }
}
```

As per Simon in the discussion [How to use explicit waits with PageFactory fields and the PageObject pattern](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/webdriver/7AGczMaV578):

> Most of the things supported by ExpectedConditions take either a WebElement or a locator. If you find one that doesn't, then all you need to do is figure out the right locator to use. Unless you've used the @FindBy annotation, this is either By.name or By.id. If you've used the annotation, then life's pretty easy --- it's just there in the code. Alternatively, don't use the PageFactory to initialise that field, and just do the lookup yourself.
>
> Remember, the PageFactory is just there to try and save you some boilerplate. You can always just not use it where it doesn't fit your particular use case.

### Conclusion

As most of the things supported by *ExpectedConditions* take either a *WebElement* or a *locator*. If you are unable to locate a dynamic element as an alternative don't use the *PageFactory* to initialise that field, and just do the lookup yourself.

Comment: I think you misunderstand from What I am looking for. What I need is, On every top of script if its possible to define WebElement path with POM structure, like what I have mentioned first example is possible.  But when we have variable which dependent on Xpath or webelement values, how can we mention it on top of script.